# sudo sysctl kern.bufcachepercent from openbsd in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, memcached, kernel, buffer, openbsd

At openBSD we have the command:

```
sudo sysctl kern.bufcachepercent
```

This sets the percent of the RAM that will be dedicated to be HD cache. How do I do that at linux Ubuntu?

Or how to mount some folder at RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my 2 cents:

first of all I don't think there's an exact counterpart for bufcachepercent in Linux kernel. Anyway you can take a look here: [vm.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) where there are some explanations on the various parameters related to vm (I think you wanna check "dirty_*", "vfs_cache_pressure" and maybe "swappiness").

Hope this helps =)

Comment: maybe I should just create a virtual disk and use my stuffs there :)